# VSCode REST client - how to get value from array in response

Tags: vscode-extensions, rest-client

I'm trying to grab the value "141" from the response using the expression

`@second = {{getall.response.body.[1].id}}`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 07 Dec 2023 09:20:21 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

[
  {
    "id": 140,
    "name": "Orlov 6 uger",
    "createdDate": "2023-12-07T09:01:29.0030238",
    "lastModifiedDate": "2023-12-07T09:07:31.4865664"
  },
  {
    "id": 141,
    "name": "Ferie 6 uger- cloud",
    "createdDate": "2023-12-07T09:11:57.7474033",
    "lastModifiedDate": "2023-12-07T09:11:57.7474044"
  }
]
```

I can the first "id" without issue using

```
# @name getfirst
GET https://{{baseUrl}}/api/todos/140

@first = {{getfirst.response.body.id}}
###
GET https://httpbin.org/get?id={{first}}
```

But when I try to access 2 item in the array with
`@second = {{getall.response.body.[1].id}}` using

```
# @name getall
GET https://{{baseUrl}}/api/todos

@second = {{getall.response.body.[1].id}}
###
GET https://httpbin.org/get?id={{second}}
```

the variable is not set

```
{
  "args": {
    "id": "{{getall.response.body.[1].id}}"
  },
```

How to I get @second to get the value "141"?

Comment: can you share where to find more info about this usage?  is this like a jq-style filter for responses?

Answer (score 3):

And the answer is:

```
@second = {{getall.response.body.1.id}}
```

Not:

```
@second = {{getall.response.body.[1].id}}
```